# How to find a value based on a last date and a unique criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anyone help with the following:

How to find a value based on last date and a unique criteria

[image]

In Column G:G, I have a range of dates. In column H:H, I have a value that consists of two separate values that I merged by =E2&"          "&F2). I merged these values as i thought it would make the process more simple. In column J:J, I have a range of unit numbers. In Column N:N, I have then used the "advanced" filter function to create a list of unique unit numbers based on the range in column J:J.

I would now like to find the latest value in column H:H based on the latest date in column G:G for each unique unit number in column N:N. Does anyone have any good ideas?. Would be so greatly appreciated as i've been stuck on this exercise for hours.

I am using Office 365 and using Excel version 1902 (Build 11328.20644).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?:

`=INDEX(H$1:H$13,MATCH(1,(J$1:J$13=N2)*(G$1:G$13=MAXIFS(G$1:G$13,J$1:J$13,N2)),0))`

Enter this formula in a new column in row 2 and drag down.
Depending on your version of excel you may need to enter this array-formula with `ctrl + shift + enter`

It indexes column H with the row number of the maximum date value for the resembling unit no.

Comment: Hi P.b. Thanks for your answer - greatly appreciated. However - when i enter the formula in, I receive an #N/A error. I made sure all columns were formatted correctly (e.g. Number, Text, etc.) but this did not solve the error.

Comment: I updated my answer, adding `$` to lock the rows from changing when dragging down the formula.ake sure you enter the formula with `ctrl + shift + enter`. Also change all Ranges ending to `13` to the last row number of your data. https://photos.app.goo.gl/g2CPc2fQcrBKgHiY8 is a picture of the working for how (in Dutch)